# Porting PostgreSQL trigger to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, postgresql, triggers, migration

I have to port a PostgreSQL trigger but since I don't have much experience on that I don't know how to change some parts. The original trigger is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER aerolinea_tr
AFTER UPDATE
ON public.aerolinea FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE public."actualizaWarehoseTemplate"();

DECLARE
  mviews RECORD;
BEGIN
  IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
    FOR mviews  IN SELECT DISTINCT template.idtemplate
                    FROM template
                    INNER JOIN vueloaerolinea ON (template.idvueloaerolinea = vueloaerolinea.idvueloaerolinea)
                    WHERE vueloaerolinea.codigolinea = old.codigolinea
    LOOP
         UPDATE detalletemplate SET idwarehose = new.idwarehouse WHERE detalletemplate.idtemplate = mviews.idtemplate;
    END LOOP;
  END IF;
  RETURN old;
END;
```

And what I have done is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER aerolinea_tr
ON aerolinea
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  -- if no row affected, the trigger ends.
  IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
  BEGIN
    RETURN;
  END;

  IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted)
  BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted)
    BEGIN
      --Update code goes here.
    END
  END
END;
```

But I can't find an equivalent to RECORD for SQL Server and I don't know how to do that part.

Comment: How are updates of `detalletemplate` correlated with the updates that invoke the trigger? How is either `template` or `vueloaerolinea` related to the table on which the trigger is defined? I mean, you don't seem to be referencing `public.aerolinea` in the body of the trigger. I kind of get the idea of what your PostgreSQL trigger does, just trying to figure out the relationship with the trigger's owner table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to use a [cursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190028%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  You can try something like this -- it's not complete because I don't know the table schema of the aerolinea table, but nonetheless, should get you going in the right direction:

```
DECLARE @idtemplate INT //Assuming this is an int
DECLARE @mviews CURSOR
DECLARE @newidwarehouse INT

SELECT @newidwarehouse = idwarehouse FROM INSERTED

SET @mviews = CURSOR FOR
SELECT DISTINCT template.idtemplate
FROM template
    INNER JOIN vueloaerolinea ON (template.idvueloaerolinea = vueloaerolinea.idvueloaerolinea)
    INNER JOIN DELETED ON DELETED.codigolinea = vueloaerolinea.codigolinea

OPEN @mviews 
FETCH NEXT
FROM @mviews INTO @idtemplate 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE detalletemplate
    SET idwarehose = @newidwarehouse 
    WHERE detalletemplate.idtemplate = @idtemplate 
FETCH NEXT
FROM @mviews INTO @idtemplate 
END
CLOSE @mviews 
DEALLOCATE @mviews
```

BTW, you don't need to check for Inserted and Deleted when checking for Updates.  You can just check for Deleted:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DELETED)
```

Comment: I quite understand what you did, but there is a problem. There is no relation between the detalletemplate and Inserted table, they have different types of primary keys and that part at the end
`JOIN Inserted ON detalletemplate.Key = Inserted.Key`
doesn't work.

Comment: I've updated the code.  Let me know if you have any issues.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly. Just one question, I heard that there is no `FOR EACH ROW` on SQL SERVER, but your code seems to work whenever multiple rows are updated, what's the trick?

Comment: @LuisM.Condor: no there is no `FOR EACH ROW` in SQL Server. It only supports statement level triggers, not row level triggers.